# Confusion with dup2(), exec() and pipes

Tags: c, unix, pipe, exec, dup2

I have been struggling to understand the concept involving the commands `dup2()`, `exec()` and pipes in conjunction.

The thing I am trying to achieve:

> Pipe the output of a program X to the input of a program Y.

Something basic like `who | sort`

> with a parent and **2** children, where the children are responsible for executing the programs and the parent passing the programs to the children.

Here is what I don't understand about pipes:

**P1)** Pipes are treated like files and should be unidirectional, but what prevents me from using one pipe for multiple unidirectional communication channels ? 
 So, let's say I have `pipe1` and three processes (`P` - parent - `C1`, `C2`, children) that have the pipe open by forking. All of these processes get to use the file descriptors. 
Let's assume we are doing everything correctly, closing the unused pipe ends,   `P` now writes something to `C1`. **What is the issue with using the pipe for communication between `C1` and `C2`again?** 
Just while writing this question, an idea hit me: Is there an issue with who reads from it while many processes may have it open simultaneously (two processes are blocking to get a read), i.e. the system cannot say for sure who wants to read the buffered data written into it? If so, how is this implemented in the system ?

I really try to understand the concept, so please bear with me.

To apply this question into real life here is some pseudocode I am dealing with:

**P:**

- `P` closes unneeded read end of `pipe1`
- `P` sends program argument ('who') to `C1` via `pipe1`
- `P` closes write end
- `P` waits for children to exit

**C1:**

- `C1` reads the argument from the read end of `pipe1`
- `C1` `dup2()`s the standard out to the write end of `pipe1`
- `C1` closes both ends of `pipe1` (because we duped it already)
- `C1` `execvp()`s the program ('who')

**C2:**

- `C2` `dup2()`s read end of `pipe1` to `stdin` so that it gets input for the program that will be executed
- `C2` closes both ends of `pipe1`
- `C2` waits for input on `stdin` of `C1` from the `dup`ed `pipe1`
- `C2` `execvp()`s program ('sort') with this input

---

Now, if I were to do it as described above, I would have no luck. 
However if I introduced another pipe `pipe2` it looks something like this:

---

**P:**

- `P` closes **both** ends of unneeded pipe `pipe2`
- `P` closes unneeded read end of `pipe1`
- `P` sends program argument ('who') to `C1` via `pipe1`
- `P` closes write end
- `P` waits for children to exit

**C1:**

- `C1` closes read end of `pipe2`
- `C1` reads the argument from the read end of `pipe1`
- `C1` `dup2()`s the standard out to the write end of `pipe2`
- `C1` closes write end of `pipe2`
- `C1` closes both ends of `pipe1` -- with `pipe2`, `pipe1` redundant in this child
- `C1` `execvp()`s the program ('who')

**C2:**

- `C2` `dup2()`s read end of `pipe2` to `stdin`
- `C2` closes both ends of `pipe1`
- `C2` waits for input on `stdin` of `C1` from the `dup`ed `pipe2`
- `C2` executes program `sort` with this input

Is the assumption correct that pipes should not be reused in multiple processes because the system may not be sure whom to "serve" ? Or is there any other reason for this ?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? Do I understand the situation correctly: P somehow receives an input like `a | b`, then creates C1 and C2, C1 executing a, C2 executing b. a's stdout should be b's stdin. Am I correct? Is this a requirement? Can't P just fork C1, and C1 can fork C2?

Comment: Also, `exec` family does not continue after the specified operation, so C1 and C2 will terminate after the commands. Which means that whenever P receives a new input like `a | b`, it will have to fork again. Since this is so, the communication between P and C1 and P and C2 seems redundant here.

Comment: @holgac Yes you are completely correct. This is a requirement. I would know how to pull it off the way you stated it.

Comment: Yes I am aware that `exec()` replaces the current process. The parent needs to communicate the programs to the children, that's a requirement.

Comment: Then as Gilles stated in his/her answer, you cannot do that. unidirectional pipe means that read/write ends use the same buffer. Instead, you need to have a pipe (p1) between P and C1, another pipe (p2) between P and C2, another (p3) between C1 and C2. Since C1 and C2 are siblings, they cannot create a pipe that each of them can share. You'll need to create p1 before C1, p2 before C2 and p3 before both C1 and C2.

Comment: @holgac Alright, having read your comment and Gilles's answer, I think I got it now, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipes are primarily designed for one-to-one communication — one writer, one reader. While there is nothing that prevents having as many readers and writers as you want, the behavior often makes this not very usable, especially with multiple readers:

- Reading from a pipe is a destructive operation: each byte sent through the pipe will be read by exactly one of the readers, whoever grabs it first. If you want to broadcast some information, you need to either use a different IPC mechanism or explicitly replicate the data (like the `tee` command).
- If there are multiple writers, their writes are interspersed in a somewhat unpredictable way. The only guarantee is that writes of size `PIPE_BUF` or less are atomic.
- If the number of writers drops to zero, the reader sees an end-of-file condition.

In the architecture you're describing, you have two independent communication channels: P sends `who` to C1, and C1 sends the output of running the `who` command to C2. In a shell script, that would be something similar to

```
echo who | { read command; exec command; } | sort
```

with `echo who` executed in the original process rather than in a subshell.

Your first proposal doesn't work because there's no way to say that the output of P will go to C1 and the output of C1 will go to C2. It's still the same pipe, so the output of P could go to C2 and the output of C1 could go back to itself, or it could be a mixture.

Comment: Okay, thanks, so you are basically confirming what I have assumed up to now. It definitely makes sense knowing that pipes are used for 1-on-1 communication for the reasons stated.